# CSP Alerts by OWASP even though CSP header is added

Tags: asp.net, content-security-policy, owasp

I am auto testing an ASP.NET web application for vulnerabilities using OWASP ZAP 2.12.0. It is raising some CSP alerts which I don't know why because CSP header is added in the Web.config. Need help to address raised alerts.

**CSP Header**

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" 
        value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:50/master/child/; 
            script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:50/master/child/;
            img-src 'self' data: http://localhost:50/master/child/; 
            style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:50/master/child/;
            object-src 'self' http://localhost:50/master/child/;
            font-src 'self' data:;
            media-src 'self';
            frame-ancestors 'self';
            upgrade-insecure-requests;
            connect-src 'self';
            frame-src 'self';" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

**Alerts**

```
Alerts (14)
CSP: Wildcard Directive (8)
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/images/ajax-loader.gif
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Login/css/style.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Styles/HTMLStyle.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches

CSP: script-src unsafe-inline (8)
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/images/ajax-loader.gif
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Login/css/style.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Styles/HTMLStyle.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches

CSP: style-src unsafe-inline (8)
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/images/ajax-loader.gif
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Login/css/style.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/App_Themes/Styles/HTMLStyle.css
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches
GET: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx
POST: http://localhost:50/Master/Child/UI/Login.aspx/GetBranches
```

Comment: You'll need to have a look at the ZAP alert details - they should explain exactly what its complaining about.

Comment: @SimonBennetts Thanks. Your comment made me read alert details carefully. CSP: Wildcard Directive (8) was raised because form-action directive was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, always look at the ZAP alert details, they should explain exactly what the problem is. If its not clear then reach out to the ZAP team via the [ZAP User Group](https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users) - we should be able to explain what the problem is and improve the alert details if needed.